# why "lock" keyword a object argument

Tags: c#, multithreading, synchronization, locking

I do not speak English and I use translator.

I'm wondering when I'm studying thread synchronization.

```
class MainApp
{
    static public int count = 0;
    static private object tLock = new object();

    static void plus()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            lock (tLock)
            {
                count++;
                Console.WriteLine("plus " + count);
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }

    static void minus()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            lock (tLock)
            {
                count--;
                Console.WriteLine("minus " + count);
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(plus));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(minus));

        t1.Start();
        t2.Start();
    }
}
```

Simple thread studying.

static private object tLock = new object();

lock (tLock) << argument value, why object argument??

Comment: To make statements inside lock threadsafe?

Comment: Side note: `Console.WriteLine($"plus {Interlocked.Increment(ref count)}");` is a faster implementation (avoid explicit `lock` if it's possible)

Comment: So that probably you can define a lock object likewise you have posted rather than locking the actual object to be updated under sync ... which may result in deadlock

Comment: Are you asking why the lock is necessary or why you need to provide an object as its parameter?

Comment: I'm sorry. I think I wrote the question too short. It's corrected.

Comment: Did you even googled for that keyword?

Comment: I searched, but there was no answer.

Comment: Your lock only blocks other threads who attempt to lock on that same object instance. If another thread tried to acquire a lock on a different object, your thread wouldn't be blocking that. Think in terms of a file system lock. If I have a write lock on one file, it would be a pretty terrible file system that stopped you from accessing any other file until I released my write lock. No we can both hold write locks on files at the same time so long as they aren't the same files.

Comment: Thank you all, i got the answer i wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why have an object argument on `lock`?

Well, because it's convenient.

First of all, it's obvious in your code example that you need some shared state between the calls to `lock`, to declare that two different sections of code are mutually exclusive. If the syntax was just `lock { }` without a parameter, like this:

```
public void DoSomestuff()
{
    lock
    {
        // Section A
    }
}

public void DoOtherStuff()
{
    lock
    {
        // Section B
    }
}
```

Then either all locks would be mutually exclusive, or would impact only their individual portion of code (so two threads could execute section A and B concurrently, but only one thread at a time could execute A). This would greatly reduce the usefulness of the keyword.

Now that we established that we need a shared state, what this state should be? We could have used a string:

```
lock ("My Section")
{
    // Section A
}
```

It would work but has a few drawbacks:

1. You expose yourself to potential collisions between the name of different sections in different libraries
2. It means that the runtime has to keep a kind of table to associate the string to a lock. Nothing too difficult, but that's some overhead

Instead, the .NET authors went for using an object argument. This solves problem 1/, as you know that another library won't have a reference to your object unless you willingly give it. But this also solves problem 2/, because **this allows the runtime to store the lock in the actual object header**. That's a pretty neat optimization.

Comment: wow it was a perfect answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following (without lock):

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        count++;
        Console.WriteLine("plus " + count);
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
```

If two threads run simultaneously:

- First thread adds one to `count` which is now 1.
- Now second thread takes over and adds one to `count` which is now 2.
- Second thread continues to print `plus 2` and loops and again adds one to `count` which is now 3.
- Now the first thread takes over and prints `plus 3` which was not intended since `count` was 1 when `WriteLine` was to be called.

When adding a locking mechanism (`lock`) the developer makes sure that a part of the code is `atomic`, i.e. is run in sequence without interruption.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        lock (tLock)
        {
            count++;
            Console.WriteLine("plus " + count);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
        }
    }
```

If you follow the same pattern here:

- First thread adds one to `count` which is now 1.
- Now second thread **tries** to take over but has to wait until the `lock` is released by the first thread.
- First thread prints `plus 1` and releases the lock.
- Now second thread can take over and add one to `count` which is now 2.
- First thread tries to take over but has to wait until the second thread releases the `lock`.
- Second thread prints `plus 2` and releases the lock.

As you  can see the *increment* and `WriteLine` are now synchronized operations.

**Edit**

After you changed the question:

The `lock` keyword requires an object of [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). It doesn't have to be an `object`. It can also be a `class`, `interface`, `delegate`, `dynamic` or `string`.

```
public static string a = string.Empty;
public static void Main()
{
    lock(a)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    }
}
```

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) for more information.